# Need to provide both Basic Authorization and SSO on Bluemix Liberty server

Tags: single-sign-on, ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty

I have a Java app running under *Websphere Liberty* on IBM Bluemix. I need to be able to authenticate users 3 different ways - ***Basic Auth, SAML SSO,*** and ***OpenAuth SSO***, in that order.

I can set up the app to do **Basic Auth** (using custom code) or **SAML SSO** (using the Bluemix *Single Sign On* service), but can't figure out a way to configure it to handle both at once. (I haven't even looked into how to do **OpenAuth** yet.)  If I configure the app to use the Bluemix *SSO* service, then my app never sees the incoming requests to check for a userid and password to try **Basic Auth** before the SSO service grabs it.

I tried changing the redirect URL in the *SSO* service to an endpoint inside my app, but then all I get is

```
CWOAU0062E: The OAuth service provider could not redirect the request because the redirect URI was not valid. Contact your system administrator to resolve the problem.
```

I can't be the only one that needs to do this.  Can anyone tell me how they did it?